# Accessing files in mounted NFS share hangs

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I am creating a NFS share. I've configured the NFS  server and also the NFS client.

My share was working perfectly fine until yesterday and now I found out it doesn't work.

I redid all the steps of NFS configuration and it still doesn't work.

My problem is that when I try to access my mount folder using `cat /mnt/nfs1.txt` (which was working perfectly fine until yesterday), nothing appears on the screen. And it looks like it is hanged or it collapsed.

```
root@ela-native:~# cat /mnt/nfs1.txt
```

After this nothing appears on the screen and also I have to close the terminal to quit.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit1**

The following are the steps in my configurations for the nfs:

NFS server:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server

sudo mkdir /var/nfs/general

sudo nano /etc/exports

  /var/nfs/general *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

sudo exportfs -a

sudo service nfs-kernel-server start
```

NFS client:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common

sudo mount 172.21.215.101:/var/nfs/general /mnt
```

And also if i run `mount -t nfs`, i get this:

```
root@ela-native:/home/salini# mount -t nfs
172.21.215.101:/var/nfs/general on /mnt type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=172.21.215.101,clientaddr=192.168.164.78)
```

I also tried `showmount -e 172.21.215.101` i got

```
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Timed out
```

**Edit2**

And the i tried `less /var/log/boot.log` in the server machine and according to my understanding, i think that there is some error with the nfs server.

```
[ESC[0;1;31mFAILEDESC[0m] Failed to start Automatically refresh installed snaps.


 [ESC[0;1;31mFAILEDESC[0m] Failed to mount /mnt/nfs/var/nfs.
    See 'systemctl status mnt-nfs-var-nfs.mount' for details.
   [ESC[0;1;33mDEPENDESC[0m] Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.
             Starting Permit User Sessions...
             Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
             Starting LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"...
             Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...
             Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
             Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
             Starting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...
    [ESC[0;32m  OK  ESC[0m] Mounted /mnt/nfs/home.
```

What is the problem here?

**Edit3**

I did `sudo ufw status numbered` and `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :111`. I got this:

```
root@wsm-ela-inc6:/home/test# sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 514/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 514/udp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 514/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 4] 514/udp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

root@wsm-ela-inc6:/home/test# sudo netstat -nlp | grep :111
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3062/rpcbind    
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      3062/rpcbind    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           3062/rpcbind    
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                3062/rpcbind
```

**Edit4**

I did :

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 2049

sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 111
```

And I tried again for `showmount` but then again the terminal give me this

`clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Timed out`

Also I tried `sudo service portmap restart` and i got `portmap: unrecognized service`. Also i tried `sudo service statd restart`, it went well. Then again i tried `showmount` but still the same problem.

**Edit5**

I also tried `netstat` and got this:

```
    tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez:52630 maa03s29-in-f2.1e:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez.z:nfs wsm-ela-inc6.csez.z:890 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez:34388 stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez:35504 maa05s06-in-f8.1e:https TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez.z:890 wsm-ela-inc6.csez.z:nfs ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez:39524 maa03s22-in-f2.1e:https TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez:shell 192.168.164.78:58982    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez:34414 stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 wsm-ela-inc6.csez:34438 stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: We can't say what you're doing wrong since you haven't said what you're doing (with regards to the NFS configuration). The NFS server is obviously not responding properly, so you should start investigating log files. If you restart the NFS server, make sure to unmount the NFS share on the client first (if possible), then remount it.

Comment: i tried to unmount it and it gu=ives me this `umount: /var/nfs/general: not found`

Comment: I also tried `showmount -e 172.21.215.101` i got `clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Timed out
`

Comment: The mount on the client is /mnt, not /var/nfs/general. That's why you get that error from umount.

Comment: Could you please explain your last comment @Kusalananda

Comment: The `umount` command would give the error `umount: /var/nfs/general: not found` if you tried to do `umount /var/nfs/general` on the client.  The directory on the client where the NFS mount is mounted is `/mnt`, and the correct command would be `umount /mnt`.

Comment: I successfully did `umount`. But now when i try to mount it, it hangs!!!

Comment: Did you restart the NFS server while the share was unmounted?

Comment: Yes, i did. And then i restarted the server and tried mounting. It then again hangs!!!

Comment: Then someone else that know more than I do about NFS on Linux would have to look at this. I only know OpenBSD. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that by disabling the firewalls on both the client and the server, the mount and showmount commands works just fine.

I've tried disabling the firewalls on server and client, and it's all sprung into life. Generally, if client and server are not on the same trusted network, running NFS between them isn't a great idea - not least because it doesn't play with dumb firewalls very well. If they are on the same trusted network, then a more blanket permit on each system for input traffic from the other will probably keep things working.

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing tcp/udp for these ports:

```
111
875
2049
20048
34729
49465
```

rather than completely opening up the firewall.